# Weird error when read data from Azure Storage Account

Tags: json, pyspark, azure-databricks

I write Azure Data factory logs to Storage account and now I want to read it and process in Databricks.
The file path like this:
path = f"abfss://{container}@{accountname}.dfs.core.windows.net/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/RESOURCEGROUPS/HR_GROUP/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY/FACTORIES/TMOFACTORY/y=2023/m=08/d=30/h=02/m=00/PT1H.json"
.And I use this command to read:
spark_df  = spark.read.option('multilines','true').json(path)
Most of files are ok. But the problem is: The File in folders have 'h=00/m=00' cannot read in Databricks.
[image]

Only files in folder 'h=00/m=00' failed, the others files is ok. For example , i read h=02/m=00 file:
[image]

If I download the file PT1H.json in folder 'h=00/m=00', change name and upload to other folder, it can be read without any problems.

I'm very confused and don't know why. I would be so grateful if you would be willing to help

Comment: can you provide PT1H.json structure.

Comment: file_location = f"abfss://folder02@dileepstorageaccount02.dfs.core.windows.net/m=00/*.json"
file_type = "json"
df = spark.read.format(file_type).option("inferSchema", "true").load(file_location)

try this